# Access constant in different modules of Android Studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I have a wearOS application combined with a mobile app in Android Studio. I communicate between those two with listeners who listen on certain paths and behave diffently dependent on the messages they recieve.

I had to define the meaning of the messages in each module and thereby violated the DRY-principle.
Is there a way to store a constant so that both modules can access it in their code and/or manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a new module for the shared code and add it as a dependency for your mobile and wear modules.

Yes, it's a little bit of overhead for just a few constants. But it helps keep things organized.